# building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX, for architecture x86_64 in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode7

When i compile my app with Xcode 7 i am getting this error

ld: in /SourceCode 2/NewRelicAgent.framework/NewRelicAgent(CustomAnalyticEvent.cxx.o), building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX, for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i have tried following links:
  1) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12960
  2) https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/45886#45886
  3) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13795

but this solutions didn't help me

let me know if you find any solution on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linked command failed with exit code 1 is probably the most general clang error. Did you try to delete the derived data? Can you show that class?

Comment: which class you are talking about ?

Comment: `CustomAnalyticEvent`

Comment: we have integrated the NewRelicAgent.framework in our application. and i am not able to see CustomAnalyticEvent class there.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Thought it's your framework and you can see the sources elsewhere. How did you install the framework? Via cocoapods? Which version of the framework do you use?

Comment: i have used (https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/mobile-monitoring-installation/getting-started/ios-installation-configuration) this steps to include NewRelicAgent.framework in my app. i havn't use cocoapods

Comment: That still doesn't tell which version do you use. I'd advise to install it via dependency manager like Cocoapods. You can manage the version this way. Read about it, it will increase your code quality. Anyway, I've added an answer to your question with link to appropriate thread on New Relic forum, hope it helps :)

Comment: ok i will check and let you know if it works thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look into the forum of the framework:

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/build-failure-in-ios-9/25963/8

They state that if you use version higher than iOS Agent v5.3.0 you should be able to skip the issue.

Comment: thanks alot...new version of NewRelicAgent.framework is only supporting xcode 7 it didn't have backward compability.

Comment: @Nik Glad it helped you. May you accept the answer if it was useful for you?